# Simplifying Counter of Checked Checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, form, dom

Is the following code a proper solution to my problem? I have a feeling it can be simplified quite a bit.

> If one of the first four checkboxes is checked the sum is 1; if two 1.5; if three 2; if four 2.5. If the bar5 is checked then it's 1 + calculated value of first four (if any is checked). Afterwards, multiply by 100.

```js
function checkboxCount() {
 var form = document.forms["calculator"];
 var bar5 = form.elements["bar5"];
 var foo = document.querySelectorAll("input[name=foo]");
 count = 0;
 
 for (var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++) {
  if (foo[i] && foo[i].checked == true) {
   count++;
  }
 }
 if (count == 1 && bar5.checked == true) {
  count = 1;
 } else if (count == 1) {
  count = 1;
 }
 if (count == 2 && bar5.checked == true) {
  count = 2;
 } else if (count == 2) {
  count = 1.5;
 }
 if (count == 3 && bar5.checked == true) {
  count = 2.5;
 } else if (count == 3) {
  count = 2;
 }
 if (count == 4 && bar5.checked == true) {
  count = 3;
 } else if (count == 4) {
  count = 2.5;
 }
 if (count == 5 && bar5.checked == true) {
  count = 3.5;
 }
 return count;
}

function calculateTotalCost() {
 var totalCost = 0;
 var printCost = document.getElementById('calculatedCost');
 totalCost = 100 * checkboxCount();

 printCost.innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}
```

```html
<form id="calculator">

<fieldset>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar1" onclick="calculateTotalCost()">Bar 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar2" onclick="calculateTotalCost()">Bar 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar3" onclick="calculateTotalCost()">Bar 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar4" onclick="calculateTotalCost()">Bar 4</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar5" onclick="calculateTotalCost()">Bar 5</label>
</fieldset>

<span id="calculatedCost"></span>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The formula can be simplified:

   1. for the first four checkboxes, if any of the items are checked, multiply the number checked by 0.5 and add 0.5
   2. Then add 1 if the fifth checkbox is checked.

   So it might be simpler to just have a reference to the first for checkboxes and then the 5th checkbox. For the first for, one can use [`document.getElementsByName('foo')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) to get a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), and then put those nodes in an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and use [`Array.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to get the first four checkboxes.

   ```
    var firstFourBars = Array.from(document.getElementsByName('foo')).slice(0, 4);
   ```

   <sub>For the record - I did consider using a CSS selector identical to that of [the answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/201690/120114) by [@200_success](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/9357/200-success) (i.e. `input[name=foo]:not(#bar5):checked`) but because the NodeList returned by [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is not live, that DOM query would need to be run each time. See point #3 for more details.</sub>
2. Event delegation can be used to avoid adding a click handler to each checkbox in the HTML. The code below utilizes [`document.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to call the `calculateTotalCost` whenever a click occurs. Because of this change, that [function receives a reference to the event as the first argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback). This allows changes based on any click anywhere but conditional logic dependent on `event.target` could be added.
3. DOM references can be stored in variables at the start of the script, so as to avoid multiple lookups (e.g. `var printCost`)
4. One other simplification:

   > ```
   > var totalCost = 0;
   > ```

   ```
    var printCost = document.getElementById('calculatedCost');
    totalCost = 100 * checkboxCount();
   ```

   There is little point in setting `totalCost` to `0` and then assigning it `100 * checkboxCount()`. Just assign it the latter product:

   ```
    var totalCost = 100 * checkboxCount();
   ```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { //Wait for DOM to be ready
  //cache DOM references
  var printCost = document.getElementById('calculatedCost');
  var firstFourBars = Array.from(document.getElementsByName('foo')).slice(0, 4);
  var bar5 = document.forms["calculator"].elements["bar5"];

  document.body.addEventListener('click', calculateTotalCost);
  // helper function for filter
  function isChecked(checkbox) {
    return checkbox.checked;
  }

  function checkboxCount() {
    var count = firstFourBars.filter(isChecked).length;
    if (count) {
      count = count * 0.5 + 0.5;
    }
    if (bar5.checked) {
      count += 1;
    }
    return count;
  }

  function calculateTotalCost(event) {
    //could conditionally execute based on event.target
    var totalCost = 100 * checkboxCount();
    printCost.innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
  }

});
```

```html
<form id="calculator">

  <fieldset>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar1">Bar 1</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar2">Bar 2</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar3">Bar 3</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar4">Bar 4</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar5">Bar 5</label>
  </fieldset>

  <span id="calculatedCost"></span>
</form>
```

### Edit

I forgot to mention that in the modified code above, it waits for the DOM to be ready before before querying it (notice the first line `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { //Wait for DOM to be ready`). Not only does it prevent attempts to access DOM elements before they exist, but the variables are scoped to the callback function instead of the global namespace.

Comment: It might make sense to call the function `calculateTotalCost` directly for the first time.

Comment: Yeah - maybe... though the OPs code doesn't function that way...

Comment: Hey @SamOnela, I just noticed a bug. If you click on `Bar 5` first, the value remains `$0` instead of `$100`. Could you please help me? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Ah yes- I have updated the code in my answer to handle that.

Comment: It works beautifully now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @SamOnela Please take a look at my completed form: [Simplifying and Improving Form Calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/201965/177275)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't taking advantage of the capabilities of `document.querySelectorAll()`.  Furthermore, `checkboxCount()` would have much simpler logic if you interpreted the requirements more literally: you should count the first four checkboxes separately from the fifth.  Finally, I would complain that `checkboxCount()` is inappropriately named, since it has logic that is much more complicated than counting.

The `querySelectorAll()` function takes a CSS selector.  Not only can the selector specify `input[name=foo]`, but you can also exclude a specific element using [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) and filter by the [`:checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) status.

Instead of `if`-`else` cases to determine the "sum", I'd use an array lookup.

Instead of writing an `onclick` handler for each `input` element, it would be better practice to eliminate all traces of JavaScript from the HTML, and attach the handlers using JavaScript.

```js
function count(selector) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(selector).length;
}

function calculateTotalCost() {
    var totalCost = 100 * (
        [0, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5][count("input[name=foo]:not(#bar5):checked")] +
        count("#bar5:checked")
    );
    document.getElementById('calculatedCost').innerHTML = "$" + totalCost;
}

document.querySelectorAll("input[name=foo]").forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('click', calculateTotalCost);
});
```

```html
<form id="calculator">

<fieldset>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar1">Bar 1</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar2">Bar 2</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar3">Bar 3</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar4">Bar 4</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="bar5">Bar 5</label>
</fieldset>

<span id="calculatedCost"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. I really appreciate it. Although your code is more concise, Sam’s solution fits better in my form, which is much larger than the code I posted.

Comment: It's not a good idea to post Code Review questions that are simplified versions of your real code, because then we can't give you the most appropriate advice.

Comment: I did not know that. It makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: I posted my full code if you’d like to take a look: [Simplifying and Improving Form Calculator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/201965/177275)