# Cake-ordering form and calculator

Tags: javascript, html, calculator, form, ecmascript-6

I’m a designer learning to code and I’ve built a simple form calculator for ordering cakes.

I would love it if you could show me how to make the code more idiomatic. How can it be more consistent, concise and simplified? How can I align it with best practices? What’s the right way to group and order it? In what other ways can I make it better?

It doesn’t need to support anything older than ECMAScript 6.

```js
// Cake-ordering calculator

const calculator = document.forms[0]
const total = calculator.elements.total

const occasionOptions = {
  party: 20,
  birthday: 25,
  anniversary: 50,
  wedding: 100
}

const sizeOptions = {
  six: 1,
  eight: 1.5,
  ten: 2,
  twelve: 2.5
}

const extrasOptions = {
  inscription: 10,
  decoration: 25,
  special: 50
}

calculator.addEventListener("click", calculateTotal)

function cake() {
  const cakes = Array.from(calculator.elements["cake"]).slice(0, 3)
  const raphael = calculator.elements.raphael

  function isChecked(checkbox) {
    return checkbox.checked
  }

  let count = cakes.filter(isChecked).length
  if (count) {
    count = count * 0.5 + 0.5
  }
  if (raphael.checked) {
    count += 1
  }
  return count
}

function occasion() {
  let occasionCost = 0
  const occasion = calculator.elements.occasion

  for (let i = 0; i < occasion.length; i++) {
    if (occasion[i].checked) {
      occasionCost = occasionOptions[occasion[i].id]
      break
    }
  }
  return occasionCost
}

function size() {
  let sizeIndex = 1
  const size = calculator.elements.size

  for (let i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {
    if (size[i].checked) {
      sizeIndex = sizeOptions[size[i].id]
      break
    }
  }
  return sizeIndex
}

function extras() {
  let extrasCost = 0
  const extras = calculator.elements.extras

  for (let i = 0; i < extras.length; i++) {
    if (extras[i].checked) {
      extrasCost = extrasCost + extrasOptions[extras[i].id]
    }
  }
  return extrasCost
}

function calculateTotal() {
  let totalCost = cake() * occasion() * size() + extras()
  total.value = "$" + totalCost.toLocaleString("en")
}

// Display "extras" fieldset when "wedding" occasion is selected

const occasions = Array.from(calculator.elements.occasion)
const fieldset = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset"))

fieldset[3].style.display = "none"

occasions.forEach(occasion => {
  occasion.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (occasion.id == "wedding") {
      fieldset[3].style.setProperty("display", "inherit")
    } else {
      fieldset[3].style.setProperty("display", "none")
    }
  })
})

// Display cost after size has been selected

const sizes = calculator.elements.size

total.style.display = "none"

for (let i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
  sizes[i].onclick = function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      total.style.setProperty("display", "inherit")
    } else {
      total.style.setProperty("display", "none")
    }
  }
}

// Disable all fieldsets except the first one

const disabledFieldsets = document.querySelectorAll(
  "fieldset:not(:first-of-type)"
)
for (let i = 0; i < disabledFieldsets.length; i++) {
  disabledFieldsets[i].disabled = true
}

// Enable fieldsets sequentially on selection

document.querySelectorAll("fieldset").forEach(fieldset => {
  fieldset.addEventListener("change", function() {
    let nextFieldset = this.nextElementSibling

    while (nextFieldset && !nextFieldset.disabled) {
      nextFieldset = nextFieldset.nextElementSibling
    }

    if (nextFieldset) {
      nextFieldset.disabled = false
    }
  })
})

// Reset form after all inputs in the first fieldset are deselected

const cakeOptions = document.querySelectorAll(
  "fieldset:first-of-type input[type=checkbox]"
)
let isChecked = false

cakeOptions.forEach(function(resetWhenAllUnchecked) {
  resetWhenAllUnchecked.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (this.checked) {
      isChecked = true
    } else {
      if (
        isChecked &&
        !document.querySelectorAll(
          "fieldset:first-of-type input[type=checkbox]:checked"
        ).length
      ) {
        calculator.reset()
        fieldset[3].style.setProperty("display", "none")
        total.style.setProperty("display", "none")
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Select Cakes</legend>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="leonardo">Leonardo</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="donatello">Donatello</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="michelangelo">Michelangelo</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="raphael">Raphael</label>
  <p>If you select more than one cake, the other cakes are discounted 50%.</p>
  <p><small>Does not apply to Raphael.</small></p>
</fieldset> 

<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose Occasion</legend>
  <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="party" required>Party</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="birthday">Birthday</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="anniversary">Anniversary</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="wedding">Wedding</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Choose Size</legend>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="six" required>6-inch</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="eight">8-inch</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="ten">10-inch</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="twelve">12-inch</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Select Extras</legend>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="inscription">Inscription</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="decoration">Decoration</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="special">Special Frosting & Icing</label>
</fieldset>

<input type="text" name="total" readonly>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Feedback

I see originally the code utilized `document.querySelector("form");` to get the form element, but has since been changed to utilize `document.forms[0]`. I had planned to mention that using that property can be quicker (since a function doesn't need to be called) but now I don't have to.

### Suggestions

#### Spread operator

Because [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) is utilized, the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) can be used to add the HTML elements. For example, instead of using `Array.from()`:

> ```
> const cakes = Array.from(calculator.elements["cake"]).slice(0, 3)
> ```

Create an array and use the spread operator to put the elements into an array:

```
const cakes = [...calculator.elements["cake"]].slice(0, 3);
```

The same is also true for `occasions` and `fieldsets`.

#### Arrow functions

Another [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) feature that can be used to simplify things is [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which is actually used in the click handler for the occasion options. For example, the function `isChecked`:

> ```
> function isChecked(checkbox) {
>   return checkbox.checked
> }
> ```

Can be simplified to an arrow function:

```
const isChecked = checkbox => checkbox.checked;
```

This could actually be done to all functions if so desired, but beware that [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) won't apply to arrow functions declared as [a function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#Constructor_vs._declaration_vs._expression#The_function_expression_(function_expression)).

#### Wait for DOM to be ready

I thought I mentioned this [in my answer to your previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/201688/120114) but realize now that I hadn't (so I had to update my answer): it is best to wait for the DOM to be ready before performing DOM queries. One way to do this is to use [`document.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add a callback function for the [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    //code to execute now that the DOM is ready
});
```

#### Cache DOM References

As I mentioned [in my answer to your previous post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/201688/120114), DOM references can be stored in variables once to avoid repeated lookups. In the code here, `cakes` and `raphael` are declared within the `cakes` function, so every time that function runs it queries the DOM for those elements.

#### Function names

The function `cake` might be better named something like `getCakeCount` or `getCakeMultiplier`, since it is returning a number.

#### Variable names

The `forEach` iterator at the end has a `currentValue` argument named `resetWhenAllUnchecked` :

> ```
> cakeOptions.forEach(function(resetWhenAllUnchecked) {
> ```

`resetWhenAllUnchecked` sounds like a boolean value. A more appropriate name would be `cakeOption`.

#### Early returns from functions

The function `occasion` could be simplified from:

> ```
> function occasion() {
>   let occasionCost = 0
>   const occasion = calculator.elements.occasion
>
>   for (let i = 0; i < occasion.length; i++) {
>       if (occasion[i].checked) {
>         occasionCost = occasionOptions[occasion[i].id]
>         break
>       }
>     }
>   return occasionCost
> }
> ```

Instead of creating `occasionCost`, updating it if an option is checked and then returning that value, one could return as soon as a found item is checked. That way there is no need to `break` out of the `for` loop nor update the return value. Some may argue that it is better to have a single return statement at the end of the function but that is a preference/convention that must be agreed upon.

```
function occasion() {
  const occasion = calculator.elements.occasion

  for (let i = 0; i < occasion.length; i++) {
    if (occasion[i].checked) {
      return occasionOptions[occasion[i].id];
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

### Rewrite

See code below using advice from suggestions above. I feel there are still some simplifications that could be done to the functions toward the end - perhaps that can be an exercise to the reader to do.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _ => {
  //DOM references
  const calculator = document.forms[0]
  const total = calculator.elements.total
  const firstThreeCakeOptions = [...calculator.elements["cake"]].slice(0, 3)
  const raphael = calculator.elements.raphael
  const cakeOptions = document.querySelectorAll(
    "fieldset:first-of-type input[type=checkbox]"
  )
  const occasions = [...calculator.elements.occasion]
  const fieldset = [...document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")]

  const occasionOptions = {
    party: 20,
    birthday: 25,
    anniversary: 50,
    wedding: 100
  }

  const sizeOptions = {
    six: 1,
    eight: 1.5,
    ten: 2,
    twelve: 2.5
  }

  const extrasOptions = {
    inscription: 10,
    decoration: 25,
    special: 50
  }

  calculator.addEventListener("click", calculateTotal)

  function cake() {
    const isChecked = checkbox => checkbox.checked;

    let count = firstThreeCakeOptions.filter(isChecked).length
    if (count) {
      count = count * 0.5 + 0.5
    }
    if (raphael.checked) {
      count += 1
    }
    return count
  }

  function occasion() {
    const occasion = calculator.elements.occasion

    for (let i = 0; i < occasion.length; i++) {
      if (occasion[i].checked) {
        return occasionOptions[occasion[i].id]
      }
    }
    return 0
  }

  function size() {
    const size = calculator.elements.size

    for (let i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {
      if (size[i].checked) {
        return sizeOptions[size[i].id]
      }
    }
    return 1
  }

  function extras() {
    let extrasCost = 0
    const extras = calculator.elements.extras

    for (let i = 0; i < extras.length; i++) {
      if (extras[i].checked) {
        extrasCost = extrasCost + extrasOptions[extras[i].id]
      }
    }
    return extrasCost
  }

  function calculateTotal() {
    const totalCost = cake() * occasion() * size() + extras()
    total.value = "$" + totalCost.toLocaleString("en")
  }

  // Display "extras" fieldset when "wedding" occasion is selected


  fieldset[3].style.display = "none"

  occasions.forEach(occasion => {
    occasion.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (occasion.id == "wedding") {
        fieldset[3].style.setProperty("display", "inherit")
      } else {
        fieldset[3].style.setProperty("display", "none")
      }
    })
  })

  // Display cost after size has been selected

  const sizes = calculator.elements.size

  total.style.display = "none"

  for (let i = 0; i < sizes.length; i++) {
    sizes[i].onclick = function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        total.style.setProperty("display", "inherit")
      } else {
        total.style.setProperty("display", "none")
      }
    }
  }

  // Disable all fieldsets except the first one

  const disabledFieldsets = document.querySelectorAll(
    "fieldset:not(:first-of-type)"
  )
  for (let i = 0; i < disabledFieldsets.length; i++) {
    disabledFieldsets[i].disabled = true
  }

  // Enable fieldsets sequentially on selection

  document.querySelectorAll("fieldset").forEach(fieldset => {
    fieldset.addEventListener("change", function() {
      let nextFieldset = this.nextElementSibling

      while (nextFieldset && !nextFieldset.disabled) {
        nextFieldset = nextFieldset.nextElementSibling
      }

      if (nextFieldset) {
        nextFieldset.disabled = false
      }
    })
  })

  // Reset form after all inputs in the first fieldset are deselected


  let isChecked = false

  cakeOptions.forEach(function(resetWhenAllUnchecked) {
    resetWhenAllUnchecked.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if (this.checked) {
        isChecked = true
      } else {
        if (
          isChecked &&
          !document.querySelectorAll(
            "fieldset:first-of-type input[type=checkbox]:checked"
          ).length
        ) {
          calculator.reset()
          fieldset[3].style.setProperty("display", "none")
          total.style.setProperty("display", "none")
        }
      }
    })
  })
});
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select Cakes</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="leonardo">Leonardo</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="donatello">Donatello</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="michelangelo">Michelangelo</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="cake" id="raphael">Raphael</label>
    <p>If you select more than one cake, the other cakes are discounted 50%.</p>
    <p><small>Does not apply to Raphael.</small></p>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose Occasion</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="party" required>Party</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="birthday">Birthday</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="anniversary">Anniversary</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="occasion" id="wedding">Wedding</label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Choose Size</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="six" required>6-inch</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="eight">8-inch</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="ten">10-inch</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="size" id="twelve">12-inch</label>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Select Extras</legend>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="inscription">Inscription</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="decoration">Decoration</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="extras" id="special">Special Frosting & Icing</label>
  </fieldset>

  <input type="text" name="total" readonly>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Hey Sam, I found a problem. If you choose "wedding", then select any of the "extras", and afterwords choose "party", "birthday", or "anniversary", "extras" are still added to the total cost instead of being subtracted. I know how to uncheck the "extras" checkboxes on "wedding" deselection – `extras.forEach(extra => extra.checked = false)` – but I would like to remember their checked state in case "wedding" is selected again.

Comment: My initial thought is to say one option is to return `0` in the `extras()` function whenever the occasion is not _wedding_, but then after considering the [Separation of Concerns principle](https://deviq.com/separation-of-concerns/) I wonder if that logic should be put into `calculateTotal()`...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the rewritten code with @SamOnela’s suggestions applied, and many other little modifications.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", _ => {
  //DOM references

  const calculator = document.forms[0]
  const total = calculator.elements.total
  const firstThreeCakeOptions = [...calculator.elements.cake].slice(0, 3)
  const size = calculator.elements.size
  const occasions = [...calculator.elements.occasion]
  const fieldset = [...document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset")]
  const extrasFieldset = fieldset[3]

  // Prices

  const occasionOptions = {
    party: 20,
    birthday: 25,
    anniversary: 50,
    wedding: 100
  }

  const sizeOptions = {
    six: 1,
    eight: 1.5,
    ten: 2,
    twelve: 2.5
  }

  const extrasOptions = {
    inscription: 10,
    decoration: 25,
    special: 50
  }

  // Calculator logic

  calculator.addEventListener("click", calculateTotal)

  function cakeMultiplier() {
    const size = calculator.elements.size
    const isChecked = checkbox => checkbox.checked

    let count = firstThreeCakeOptions.filter(isChecked).length
    if (count) {
      count = count * 0.5 + 0.5
    }
    if (raphael.checked) {
      count += 1
    }
    return count
  }

  function occasionCost() {
    const occasion = calculator.elements.occasion

    for (let i = 0; i < occasion.length; i++) {
      if (occasion[i].checked) {
        return occasionOptions[occasion[i].id]
      }
    }
    return 0
  }

  function sizeCost() {
    for (let i = 0; i < size.length; i++) {
      if (size[i].checked) {
        return sizeOptions[size[i].id]
      }
    }
    return 1
  }

  function extrasCost() {
    const extras = calculator.elements.extras
    let extrasCost = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < extras.length; i++) {
      if (extras[i].checked) {
        extrasCost = extrasCost + extrasOptions[extras[i].id]
      }
    }
    return extrasCost
  }

  function calculateTotal() {
    const totalCost =
      cakeMultiplier() * occasionCost() * sizeCost() + extrasCost()
    total.value = "$" + totalCost.toLocaleString("en")
  }

  // Display "extras" fieldset when "wedding" occasion is selected

  extrasFieldset.style.display = "none"

  occasions.forEach(occasion => {
    occasion.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (occasion.id == "wedding") {
        extrasFieldset.style.setProperty("display", "inherit")
      } else {
        extrasFieldset.style.setProperty("display", "none")
      }
    })
  })

  // Display cost after size has been selected

  total.style.display = "none"

  size.forEach(i => {
    i.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if (this.checked) {
        total.style.setProperty("display", "inherit")
      }
    })
  })

  // Disable all fieldsets except the first one

  function disableFieldsets() {
    const disabledFieldsets = document.querySelectorAll(
      "fieldset:not(:first-of-type)"
    )

    for (let i = 0; i < disabledFieldsets.length; i++) {
      disabledFieldsets[i].disabled = true
    }
  }

  disableFieldsets()

  // Enable fieldsets sequentially on selection

  document.querySelectorAll("fieldset").forEach(fieldset => {
    fieldset.addEventListener("change", function() {
      let nextFieldset = this.nextElementSibling

      while (nextFieldset && !nextFieldset.disabled) {
        nextFieldset = nextFieldset.nextElementSibling
      }

      if (nextFieldset) {
        nextFieldset.disabled = false
      }
    })
  })

  // Reset form after all inputs in the first fieldset are deselected

  let isChecked = false

  document
    .querySelectorAll("fieldset:first-of-type input[type=checkbox]")
    .forEach(function(cakeOption) {
      cakeOption.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        if (this.checked) {
          isChecked = true
        } else {
          if (
            isChecked &&
            !document.querySelectorAll(
              "fieldset:first-of-type input[type=checkbox]:checked"
            ).length
          ) {
            calculator.reset()
            disableFieldsets()
            extrasFieldset.style.setProperty("display", "none")
            total.style.setProperty("display", "none")
          }
        }
      })
    })
})
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>Select Cakes</legend>
  <input type=checkbox name=cake id=leonardo>
  <label for=leonardo>Leonardo</label>
  
  <input type=checkbox name=cake id=donatello>
  <label for=donatello>Donatello</label>
  
  <input type=checkbox name=cake id=michelangelo>
  <label for=michelangelo>Michelangelo</label>
  
  <input type=checkbox name=cake id=raphael>
  <label for=raphael>Raphael</label>
  
  <p>If you select more than one cake, the other cakes are discounted 50%.
  <p><small>Does not apply to Raphael.</small>
</fieldset> 

<fieldset>
<legend>Choose Occasion</legend>
  <input type=radio name=occasion id=party required>
  <label for=party>Party</label>
  
  <input type=radio name=occasion id=birthday>
  <label for=birthday>Birthday</label>
  
  <input type=radio name=occasion id=anniversary>
  <label for=anniversary>Anniversary</label>
  
  <input type=radio name=occasion id=wedding>
  <label for=wedding>Wedding</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Choose Size</legend>
  <input type=radio name=size id=six required>
  <label for=six>6-inch</label>
  
  <input type=radio name=size id=eight>
  <label for=eight>8-inch</label>
  
  <input type=radio name=size id=ten>
  <label for=ten>10-inch</label>
  
  <input type=radio name=size id=twelve>
  <label for=twelve>12-inch</label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<legend>Select Extras</legend>
  <input type=checkbox name=extras id=inscription>
  <label for=inscription>Inscription</label>
  
  <input type=checkbox name=extras id=decoration>
  <label for=decoration>Decoration</label>
  
  <input type=checkbox name=extras id=special>
  <label for=special>Special Frosting & Icing</label>
</fieldset>

<input type=text name=total readonly>
<input type=submit value=Submit>
</form>
```

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit on the "many other little modifications"? It's a bit difficult to see what you did without a diffing tool. Thanks :)

Comment: @Vogel612 First and foremost, I applied Sam’s suggestions, then I tidied up the JavaScript code by reordering it and renaming a few things, and I also made the HTML a bit more concise and more readable.

Comment: The code snippet in my answer should be the starting point.